# Skipping output binding because one or more optional files are missing

Tags: matlab, nextflow

I have a process which execute a matlab code. The process runs without any error. But the `out_ch.view()` shows nothing and I am not getting any output in the out directory. The process is like:

```
process mostest2 {
publishDir params.out2, mode:'copy'

input:
tuple val(a1),path(t1),path(z1),path(z2) from m2
output:
path("*") optional true into most

script:
"""
cd /cluster/projects/p33/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/mostest_code/
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r "zmat_orig_file='${z1}';zmat_perm_file='${z2}'; num_eigval_to_keep='${a1}'; out='mostest_out_${a1}.mat'; mostest_mental; exit"
echo ${a1} 'done'
"""
}
most.view()
```

Any Help? The log is below:

```
>     Nov-12 10:57:31.557 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue
> .command.run
>     Nov-12 10:57:31.557 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [16/5ff182] Submitted process > mostest2 (4)
>     Nov-12 10:57:31.576 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue
> .command.run
>     Nov-12 10:57:31.577 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [64/fbe920] Submitted process > mostest2 (24)
>     Nov-12 10:57:31.586 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue
> .command.run
>     Nov-12 10:57:31.586 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [bd/1d4cde] Submitted process > mostest2 (6)
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.622 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2149; name: mostest2 (16); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/a6/f6e3f3fb9c1aaf9cfddbe05d1024c1]
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.667 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.788 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2134; name: mostest2 (1); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/d2/aa6e7d0b27fbc481cae3f665da13cd]
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.793 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.838 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2139; name: mostest2 (6); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/bd/1d4cde31cae3985e979ddae9061cab]
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.865 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.884 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2155; name: mostest2 (22); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/e6/7d42b590b5e6078e678e2153a6e8d4]
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.888 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.891 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2146; name: mostest2 (13); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/49/3824fbbfbee5083fdd4f00644aec30]
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.895 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.906 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2141; name: mostest2 (8); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/ba/7b9b878692326aa9f5b34b05785ba9]
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.909 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.939 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2154; name: mostest2 (21); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/e8/06a2c83185d95b28e9003d5de21217]
>     Nov-12 10:58:11.943 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.024 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2138; name: mostest2 (5); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/25/52cf954e7b2c18c5423a2a44d67ac6]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.030 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.032 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2147; name: mostest2 (14); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/90/f9463facb33de9334ff65c7a64a660]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.050 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.060 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2151; name: mostest2 (18); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/2c/a2d9065744e0092a50e7f269584fcd]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.076 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.094 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2136; name: mostest2 (3); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/20/84672fbaf145f53742ea71277e605e]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.098 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.127 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2140; name: mostest2 (7); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/9c/86018fc1ce92b749d76153d7561859]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.132 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.195 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2150; name: mostest2 (17); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/7d/4c557aa1448ad0b2f19040cef536b8]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.197 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.203 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2145; name: mostest2 (12); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/1a/f4b2efd106877b369c14edb678beeb]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.207 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.221 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2153; name: mostest2 (20); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/1c/14644e7106904228c5c92a25da1263]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.224 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.226 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2144; name: mostest2 (11); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/de/790d6fff78bc8edae1154f0a98948f]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.230 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.247 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2152; name: mostest2 (19); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/69/27df74f5ca9a447b6c46edfc46574f]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.249 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.253 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2142; name: mostest2 (9); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/d2/e75e2ad9a36ab170d7df93354b6fbf]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.259 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.272 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2158; name: mostest2 (25); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/15/81e1a697f77d135234f930fcea091c]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.275 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.276 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2148; name: mostest2 (15); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/41/4bc594aa15d2510528c076e1aeab11]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.279 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.280 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2137; name: mostest2 (4); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/16/5ff18271959c2eed4d6ca0965bc190]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.282 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.288 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2156; name: mostest2 (23); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/08/1f0ce40952a734160703efc5178c22]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.290 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.291 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2135; name: mostest2 (2); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/6d/cb613bc7ee9f98b064f5af0ae821a1]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.293 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.303 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2143; name: mostest2 (10); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/bc/7fee5c2db1cee6423a6a6628932e08]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.305 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.352 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id:
> 2157; name: mostest2 (24); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -;
> workDir:
> /gpfs/projects01/p33/cluster/users/mohammadzr/metabolomics/scripts/work/64/fbe920bf4190925804cd95b9799b90]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.354 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Process mostest2 > Skipping output
> binding because one or more optional files are missing:
> fileoutparam<0>
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.354 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await > all processes finished
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.355 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await > all barriers passed
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.366 [main] DEBUG nextflow.util.ThreadPoolManager - Thread pool 'PublishDir' shutdown completed (hard=false)
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.373 [main] DEBUG nextflow.trace.WorkflowStatsObserver - Workflow completed >
> WorkflowStats[succeededCount=25; failedCount=0; ignoredCount=0;
> cachedCount=2133; pendingCount=0; submittedCount=0; runningCount=0;
> retriesCount=0; abortedCount=0; succeedDuration=16m 55s;
> failedDuration=0ms; cachedDuration=6d 4h 41m 15s;loadCpus=0;
> loadMemory=0; peakRunning=25; peakCpus=25; peakMemory=0; ]
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.510 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cache.CacheDB - Closing CacheDB done
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.619 [main] DEBUG nextflow.util.ThreadPoolManager - Thread pool 'FileTransfer' shutdown completed (hard=false)
>     Nov-12 10:58:12.620 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Execution complete -- Goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

Nextflow just expects [output](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#outputs) files in the working directory. By changing directories (i.e. `cd /cluster/projects/blah`), you're navigating away from the working directory to run your MATLAB code. The reason the output of [view()](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#view) is empty, is because you've used the [optional](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#optional-outputs) keyword to declare your output file(s), and these won't exist in the working directory. To help make your pipeline portable, avoid using absolute paths. What you want (e.g. using [DSL 2](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html) syntax) is to be able to run the command from within the working directory and then name the output file in the output declaration:

```
process mostest2 {

    publishDir params.out2, mode:'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(a1) ,path(t1), path(z1), path(z2)

    output:
    path("mostest_out_${a1}.mat"), optional: true

    script:
    """
    matlab \\
        -nodisplay \\
        -nosplash \\
        -r "zmat_orig_file='${z1}'; zmat_perm_file='${z2}'; num_eigval_to_keep='${a1}'; out='mostest_out_${a1}.mat'; mostest_mental; exit"
    """
}
```

I'm not familiar with MATLAB but from a quick look of the [MATLAB (Linux)](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html) docs, it looks like you don't want `-r` at all. This option is intended for interactive commands/workflows. I think you want `-batch` instead:

> -batch *statement*
>
> Execute MATLAB script, statement, or function non-interactively.
> MATLAB:
>
> - Starts without the desktop
> - Does not display the splash screen
> - Executes *statement*
> - Displays figure windows, unless combined with the `-noFigureWindows` or `-nodisplay` options
> - Displays user-generated modal dialog boxes, but does not display
>   unprompted modal dialog boxes
> - Disables changes to preferences
> - Disables toolbox caching
> - Logs text to `stdout` and `stderr`
> - Exits automatically with exit code 0 if *statement* executes
>   successfully. Otherwise, MATLAB terminates with a non-zero exit code.
>
> *statement* is MATLAB code enclosed in double quotation marks. If
> *statement* is the name of a MATLAB function or script, do not specify
> the file extension. Any required file must be on the MATLAB search
> path or in the startup folder.
>
> Use the `-batch` option in non-interactive scripting or command line
> workflows. Do not use this option with the `-r` option.
>
> To test if a session of MATLAB is running in batch mode, call the
> [batchStartupOptionUsed](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/batchstartupoptionused.html) function.
>
> Example: `-batch "myscript"`